# constructor for dict implementation in Python

Tags: python

I'm implementing a TreeDict in Python (using BinarySearchTree)

I'm having hard time creating the constructor for it:
Here are some cases that I have to take care of:

```
1. dict = TreeDict()                               
2. dict = TreeDict((x, str(x)) for x in range(50))  
3. dict = TreeDict({"1" : 1, "2" : 2})
4. dict = TreeDict(one = 1, two = 2)
```

I have these for my constructor:

```
def __init__(self, key=None, value=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

so,

case #1: it will create an empty TreeDict

case #4: it will store keyword args in kwargs

How do we take care of case #2 and #3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases, it's best to use one of the ABC's (abstract base classes) already provided by python:

```
from collections import MutableMapping

class TreeDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreeDict, self).__init__()
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

The idea is that collections supplies many of the methods you need to make a mapping based on only a few that you provide.  In this case, you need to provide:

`__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__` and collections supplies the rest (`__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `pop`, `popitem`, `clear`, `update`, and `setdefault`).  Not bad ...

Comment: Note that the ABC's were moved to a different module namespace in Python 3.3. If you are using Python 3.3 or later, the import statement will be `from collections.abc import MutableMapping` instead of `from collections import MutableMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Then do logic as needed on the values of `args` and `kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ `type(args[i])` or `args[i].__class__.__name__` to find out, whether your parameter is a `tuple` or a `dict` and process `args[i]` accordingly.